# How to store the variable in Resource Directory?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

I want to store all the variables in Resource Directory and Save all the information after calculation and display that information on the page.I know how to dispay the information I don't know how to save the information after calculation please tell me how to do it??

Can you show me little example like this I try to find this type of Example but i couldn't...

Comment: Solutions to data persistence have been around since the dawn of computing. In .NET you have a fine selection of DB Support, File IO and a plethora of object serialization formats. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Properties.Resources is read only to application

Answer (score 0):

Resource Dictionaries are not what you're looking for. These are intended to store static data such as styles and templates not inteded to be changed at runtime by the application. However, if you need to dynamically load XAML into your application you need to use the `XamlReader` class. [Here is an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml.aspx)